# Where the place to put the new UserId into DB after user is logged in with OpenId Connect for a first time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.1

Need to register a new user when he accessing the site for the first time through OpenIdConnect by local IdentityServer4. Found "best place" to do that in `OnUserInformationReceived` event, but not sure how to access EF DbContext in event handler (Startup class). There is no DI for getting pre-configured instance of DbContext (which requests other dependencies in it's constructor).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            // ...

            options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = OnUserInformationReceived;
        });

    // ...
}

private Task OnUserInformationReceived(UserInformationReceivedContext c)
{
    var userId = c.User.Value<string>(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub);

    // Call DbContext to insert User entry if doesn't exist.
    // Or there is another place to do that?

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`UserInformationReceivedContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.userinformationreceivedcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class includes a [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.basecontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_BaseContext_HttpContext) property, which itself includes a [`RequestServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestservices?view=aspnetcore-1.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_RequestServices) property. This `RequestServices` property is of type [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netcore-2.1), which can be used for accessing services registered in the Dependency Injection container.

Here's an example using [`GetService<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservice?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
private Task OnUserInformationReceived(UserInformationReceivedContext c)
{
    var userId = c.User.Value<string>("sub");    
    var dbContext = c.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<YourDbContext>();

    // Use dbContext here.

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```